# Create batch file to copy contents of one SQL Server database to another

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I need to create a batch file (script) to copy entire content of one SQL Server database to another. Source database is local for the machine. What command line tools and commands therein I could use? Destination database can be dropped entirely.

Also, I need to run a pair of SQL queries afterwards, also from batch file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read about Run Transact-SQL Script Files Using sqlcmd from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx

Answer (score 1):

first u need to create your sql queries then u can use this command to run it via batch file

```
sqlcmd -S %computername%\%SName% -U %UName% -P %Pwd%  -i SQL_DB.sql >> _Deploy.txt 2>&1
```

this command gets computer name and sqlserver instance name and user name and password and run SQL_DB.sql file near batch file that contains our queries and save the result in a text file named _deploy.txt